# Relative layout repeatedly multiple views in same location

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-relativelayout, android-studio-2.1

In relative layout containing one edit text, one spinner one image in add new contact form. the same layout repeatedly in same position when i click add button android. Here i attached my code in xml. Thanks for help

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/addcontact_relative2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addcontact_relative1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addcontact_edit_mail"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Mail"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_rounded"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addcontact_mail_spin"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_rounded"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addcontact_edit_mail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:entries="@array/types"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addcontact_add_email_image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/peopleadd"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The point is that you are using **@+id** for referencing already created ids, therefore, you create NEW ids and the elements don't refer to the ids you expect them to. solution: change **@+d** to **@id** when referencing (i.e.: in `toRightOf`). Please study the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of the RelativeLayout. Either change it to LinearLayout with an orientation of vertical(if you want one under the other) or horizontal. Or you can add verious things to your layout.xml in your RelativeLayout, such as various android:layout_align modes.

Comment: I am using root layout is relative layout but  can change linear layout for this position.